# WPF shared property

Tags: wpf, textbox, styles

I have a question which I guess it's some basic knowledge which I missing in WPF.

I set default width (generix.XML) to Textbox with some Minim width for the textbox

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="50"/>
</Style>
```

I have two deferent controls which holds text box. Both Textboxes has same width..
I which to add some property to one of the controls which will declare the width of the textbox, and will override its width declaration, in a way that the textbox will 'find' to this property.

here is some drawing describes my requirement:

[image: controls]

Update:

I just figure out that I didn't described one more importing thing. 
I Have some DataTemplate which uses the textbox. As I wrote above, I have two controls which have the same DataType (MyData) I also created DateTemplate to display MyData. I would like that each control will display the textbox (from the datatemple) with different width.

update 2:
here is some more code

1- The dataTemplate to my data where is using textbox

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ml:MyData}">
    <Border  BorderBrush="Transparent" ClipToBounds="True"  Style="{StaticResource errorBorder}">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding MyText}"/>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

2- the way I used the datatemplate which uses the Textbox.

```
<ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,1,10,1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="{Binding}" />
```

This contentPresentor is been displayed in two diffrent controls. and as I wrote before, I would like that each control will display the textbox in diferent width

It's look like I miss some basic knloage (attached proerty? logic/visual tree?).

Thanks, Leon

Comment: Why not setting the Width property of the TextBox?

Comment: Thank you Amittai.Please see my update in my question.Thanks, Leon

Comment: Can you add simplified version of your XAML, which shows how you the TextBox in the DataTemplate, and how do you use the DataTemplate in the controls

Comment: Thank you Amittai. I added some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question, the main idea in DataTemplate is that you have specific graphical representation for some data. You can read more about it in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx).
If you want to customize your TextBox, and have it different properties inside different UserControls, you might want to use [ControlTemplate](http://www.wpftutorial.net/templates.html).
The thing is that if you want to control properties of specific control (in this case TextBox with some border) you should use ControlTemplate.
Your XAML should look something like:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <--! define the ControlTemplate here with some Width property-->
<ControlTemplate>
```

and the Control which use it will have TextBox (as you defined it, with Border):

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,1,10,1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="{Binding}" Width="50"/>
```